# Extract last working day of every month in bigquery

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, hql

Currently I'm using the below code:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(example, INTERVAL 1 DAY) , 
       FORMAT_DATE("%A", DATE_SUB(example, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2013-01-1', '2030-04-01', INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AS example
```

The output which I'm getting is:

```
2012-12-31    Monday
2013-03-31    Sunday
2013-06-30    Sunday
2013-09-30    Monday
2013-12-31    Tuesday
2014-03-31    Monday
2014-06-30    Monday
2014-09-30    Tuesday
```

The expected output is:

```
2012-12-31    Monday
2013-03-29    Friday
2013-06-28    Friday
2013-09-30    Monday
2013-12-31    Tuesday
2014-03-31    Monday
2014-06-30    Monday
2014-09-30    Tuesday
```

I'm trying to extract the last working day for each quarter(3 months of timegap). But i couldn't exclude saturdays and sundays.

It would be great if someone help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
SELECT case when FORMAT_DATE("%A", DATE_SUB(example, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = 'Sunday' 
                then date_sub(DATE_SUB(example, INTERVAL 1 DAY), interval 2 day)
            when FORMAT_DATE("%A", DATE_SUB(example, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = 'Saturday' 
                then date_sub(DATE_SUB(example, INTERVAL 1 DAY), interval 1 day)
                 else DATE_SUB(example, INTERVAL 1 DAY) end as d1,
       case when FORMAT_DATE("%A", DATE_SUB(example, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) in ('Saturday','Sunday') 
                then 'Friday' 
                 else FORMAT_DATE("%A", DATE_SUB(example, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) end
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2013-01-1', '2030-04-01', INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AS example
order by d1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in your query `ORDER BY your_date ASC`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
create temp function getLastBusinessDayOfMonth(next_month_first_day date) as ((
  select as struct month_last_business_day,
    format_date("%A", month_last_business_day) day_of_week
  from unnest([struct(next_month_first_day - 1 as month_last_day, extract(dayofweek from next_month_first_day) as adjust)]),
  unnest([struct(month_last_day - if(adjust > 2, 0, adjust) as month_last_business_day)])
));
select getLastBusinessDayOfMonth(sample).*
from unnest(generate_date_array('2013-01-1', '2014-11-01', interval 3 month)) as sample
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also can calculate the diffenece to the last workday with ELT().

This function returns the difference, in days, to the last workday

```
ELT(dayofweek(example), '2','3','1','1','1','1','1')
```

**Sample for MariaDB**

```
SELECT 
    example as org
    , example - INTERVAL ELT(dayofweek(example), '2','3','1','1','1','1','1') DAY AS LAST_WORKDAY
    , DATE_FORMAT(example - INTERVAL ELT(dayofweek(example), '2','3','1','1','1','1','1') DAY,'%W') AS WEEKDAY
FROM (
SELECT date('2013-01-01') + interval seq MONTH as example from seq_0_to_4) as d;
```

**Sample for MySQL**

```
SELECT 
    example as org
    , example - INTERVAL ELT(dayofweek(example), '2','3','1','1','1','1','1') DAY AS LAST_WORKDAY
    , DATE_FORMAT(example - INTERVAL ELT(dayofweek(example), '2','3','1','1','1','1','1') DAY,'%W') AS WEEKDAY
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2013-01-1', '2030-04-01', INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AS example;
```

**Result**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT 
    -> example as org
    -> , example - INTERVAL ELT(dayofweek(example), '2','3','1','1','1','1','1') DAY AS LAST_WORKDAY
    -> , DATE_FORMAT(example - INTERVAL ELT(dayofweek(example), '2','3','1','1','1','1','1') DAY,'%W') AS WEEKDAY
    -> FROM (
    -> SELECT date('2013-01-01') + interval seq MONTH as example from seq_0_to_4) as d ;
+------------+--------------+----------+
| org        | LAST_WORKDAY | WEEKDAY  |
+------------+--------------+----------+
| 2013-01-01 | 2012-12-31   | Monday   |
| 2013-02-01 | 2013-01-31   | Thursday |
| 2013-03-01 | 2013-02-28   | Thursday |
| 2013-04-01 | 2013-03-29   | Friday   |
| 2013-05-01 | 2013-04-30   | Tuesday  |
+------------+--------------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```